# Sorting a dynamic array in c

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic, heap-memory

I'm trying to create a function in order to create a ascending order list by using "malloc" and "realloc".

Here is the structure:

```
struct sorted_dyn_array {
  int *array;
  int length;
  int capacity;
};
```

returns a pointer to a sorted_dyn_array structure, allocated on the heap

```
const int BUFFER_INIT_SIZE = 5;
const int KEY_NOT_FOUND = -1;


struct sorted_dyn_array *arr_create(void) {
   struct sorted_dyn_array *new_arr = malloc(sizeof (struct sorted_dyn_array));
   new_arr->array = malloc(sizeof (int) * BUFFER_INIT_SIZE);
   new_arr->length = 0;
   new_arr->capacity = 5;
   return new_arr;
}
```

free memory:

```
void free_arr(struct sorted_dyn_array *arr) {
  free(arr->buffer);
  free(arr);
}

int arr_length(struct sorted_dyn_array * arr) {
  return arr->length;
}

int arr_capacity(struct sorted_dyn_array *arr) {
  return arr->capacity;
}
```

using binary search find the position for the next number:

```
int find_pos(int item, int arr[], int len) {
 int low = 0;
 int high = len-1;
 if (arr[0] >= item) {
 return 0;
 }
 if(arr[0] < item) {
 return KEY_NOT_FOUND;
 }
 while (low <= high) {
   int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
   if (arr[mid] == item) {
   return mid;
   } else if (arr[mid] < item) {
   low = mid + 1;
   } else {
   high = mid - 1;
   }
   if(arr[high] < item) {
   return high;
   }
   }
   return KEY_NOT_FOUND;
 }


int arr_find_successor(struct sorted_dyn_array *arr, int k) {
  int len = arr_length(arr);
  return find_pos(k,arr->buffer,len);  
}
```

insert a number, if it is already in the list, return false. Otherwise, insert a number into the list then return true

```
bool arr_insert(struct sorted_dyn_array *arr, int k) {
  int pos = arr_find_successor(arr,k);
  if(arr_length(arr) == arr_capacity(arr)) {
  arr->capacity *= 2;
  arr->array = realloc(arr->buffer, sizeof(int) * arr->capacity);// realloc if the     length exceed the capacity
}
if (pos == KEY_NOT_FOUND) {// If the number is greater than all the number in array,put it at the end
  int l = arr->length;
  arr->array[l] = k;
  arr->length++;
  }
  if (pos != KEY_NOT_FOUND){
   for (int c = arr->length - 1; c >= pos; c--)
      arr->array[c+1] = array->array[c];
      arr->array[pos] = k;
      arr->length++;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Main function:

```
int main () {
  struct sorted_dyn_array *myarray = arr_create();

  int next = 0;
  while (scanf("%d",&next) == 1) {
    int next_item = next;
    arr_insert(myarray, next_item);
    printf("%d\n",next_item);

   free_arr(myarray);
 }
}
```

However, when I try to scanf the second number it says

```
    int arr_length(struct sorted_dyn_array * arr) {
      return arr->length;
    }
```

invalid access memory. Can somebody help me out? I spend like a whole afternoon and still cant find where goes wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for showing thorough attempt.

Comment: have you considered using Valgrind?

Comment: The 5 in `arr_create()` should be `BUFFER_INIT_SIZE`.

Comment: Reading the value of `arr[0]` in `find_pos` is undefined behavior when the array is empty.

Comment: Looking at the actual comparisons in `find_pos`: it's a fundamental property of integers that either `arr[0] >= item` or `arr[0] < item` is true. The `while` loop is never reached.

Comment: Note that your code is working on a different structure; there is no `buffer` in the structure definition shown.  (Simple fix: `buffer` -> `array`)  Also, `arr->array[c+1] = array->array[c];` should be `arr->array[c+1] = arr->array[c];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `free_arr` at the end of the loop in `main` means that the second iteration is operating on freed memory when it calls `arr_length`.

This results in undefined behaviour but you've been quite lucky to crash so quickly.  Are you running a Windows debug build?  (This will set freed memory to a known 'bad' value - `0xFEEEFEEE` - to help you spot problems like this.)

The fix is simple here - just move the `free_arr(myarray)` call outside the loop.

```
int main () {
    struct sorted_dyn_array *myarray = arr_create();

    int next = 0;
    while (scanf("%d",&next) == 1) {
        int next_item = next;
        arr_insert(myarray, next_item);
        printf("%d\n",next_item);
    }
    free_arr(myarray);
}
```

Comment: I got a `sdl(21291) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fb14bc03a50: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug` message.  Your fix does fix the problems once the code compiles.